# Laravel App Build and Deploy in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: laravel, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build and deploy Laravel app in Azure DevOps Pipeline.
But there is no template about Laravel even at marketplace.

How can I build and deploy on server...   Windows environment.

I have checked at GitHub about that and it is also providing only testing Laravel app.
Azure only providing PHP generic template.
Also searched much on Google no result found about that.

I want to build it and create a package which can be then deployed on server.
Or directly deploy it on server and run app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a local environment on windows ( think Laragon ), you would then add that to your Azure pipeline....other alternative is WSL on windows to run Linux locally.

Something akin to this:

Go to Web component under Marketplace module in Azure Portal and search for Web App + MySQL.

Click create and fill out the form. You can reuse an existing database or create a new one.

Configure the Web App as a PHP application. On the web app sidebar menu, go to Settings >Configuration > General settings > Stack settings. Change stack to PHP and do not forget to choose the version of PHP your application is using and Save the Changes.

We need to install composer on the web app. Go to App service and click on your web app application, then find Extensions under development tools on its menu sidebar.
Click the Add button > choose extension, then search for "Composer". Agree to Legal terms and click ok.

Upload your application

Go to settings > configuration > path mappings > virtuals application and directories. Change the default folder from “site\wwwroot” to “site\wwwroot\public” and Save the Changes.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I am just using for development. Also i don't have paid azure and extension not available in free one.

Comment: I wana use my own system to deploy and run tests.  Which is windows. And I don't know about Laragon

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](https://gist.github.com/zanechua/a67ed1de1fff20639edb121bdb0b6e4d).
Not already tested but seems good.

Comment: Yes but its using Ubuntu I have windows...